# Exposing SCDF services from a Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

Base problem is how to access a Spring Cloud Data Flow service from outside the Kubernetes cluster?

By default SCDF apps will be deployed as servcies with type 'ClusterIP'. From my understanding 'ClusterIP' services cannot be exposed from a cluster?
I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_accessing_an_application_from_outside_the_cluster), i.e. adding deployment properties for both, load balancer and node port, but the services keep being deployed with type 'ClusterIP'.

```
stream deploy test --properties "deployer.http.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true"
stream deploy test --properties "deployer.http.kubernetes.createNodePort=32123"
```

And in general: deployer properties will be applied to all apps of a stream, isn't there a nice way to do such things for each single app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Minikube, you will deploy a stream with `NodePort`, so you can interact with it via HTTP/PORT when the app is up and running. That can be set up with `deployer.<app-name>.kubernetes.createNodePort=32123` deployment property.

When running in a real K8s cluster, however, you'd have to use `deployer.http.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true`, so a real LB can be automatically created for the app. Likewise, you will then have an External-IP to interact with the app.

You shouldn't be doing both for a given app, however. It depends on the K8s environment where you're attempting to deploy the stream.

Both of the above-described deployment properties are optionally configurable at each app or for all the apps in a given stream. The global setting can be triggered via `deployer.*...` pattern.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: thanks for the clarification so far! Due to some enterprise-regulations I ended up with a (finally) working 'ClusterIP'-service + Ingress setup.
Now a new problem comes up: the service name is hardwired in the Ingress config, which forces me to update the Ingress config after each re-deployment. This is because SCDF adds the `vXXX` suffix on the service name. Any way/experiences to deal with that - either to get rid of the `vXXX` suffix or to have some kind of dynamic Ingress?

Comment: I recently replied to a similar requirement in Gitter - see [here](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow?at=5d604c3338f9c27238c014e3). I hope this helps.